# How to write to a csv file using R shiny inputs and sqldf

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use a go button to write to a csv file such that what the users input on the shiny inputs it will be written to a csv file i loaded, please refer to below code:

```
REAL_ESTATE <- read.csv("Real_Estate.csv")

shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session){

  ntext <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
         query <- paste0("INSERT INTO REAL_ESTATE (ID_No,  Invoice_Number, Payment_Due_Date, Payment_Date, Payment_Type, Paid_Amount)",
                         "VALUES ('", input$ID, "','", input$`Invoice No.` ,"','",input$Due, "','",input$On, "','",input$Type, "',",
                                  input$Msisdn, "','",input$amt,"','")
         queryres <- sqldf(query)
  })

  output$nText <- renderTable({
      nText()
  })    

})
```

I get the error: `Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection`

I have set the path to the correct directory of the file but it does not work.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow, please could you type in the console `dput(head(REAL_ESTATE))`to understand your data? That help us to help you.

Comment: Hello, it's an empty csv table that i want to write to:

structure(list(ID_No = logical(0), Invoice_Number = logical(0), 
    Payment_Due_Date = logical(0), Payment_Date = logical(0), 
    Payment_Type = logical(0), Paid_Amount = logical(0)), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame")

Thank you.